# $A\otimes_F M_{n}(F) \cong M_{n}(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ a $F-$algebra, where $F$ is a field. Then $A\otimes_{F} M_{n}(F)\cong M_{n}(A).$

Now, I defined a function from $A\otimes_{F} M_{n}(F)$ to $ M_{n}(A),$ given by $\sum a\otimes (c_{ij}) \mapsto \sum(c_{ij}a)$ and I want to prove it is an isomorphism.

My problem is that I don't know how to prove it is injective, it becomes quite confusing.

edit: I skipped the part I used the universal property of the tensor product to see it is well defined.

Comment: Can you show that $M_n(A)$ has the universal property required of the tensor product?

Answer (score 1):

As an $F$-module $M_n(F)\cong F^{n^2}$. Then $A\otimes_F F^{n^2}\cong
A^{n^2}$. This is just taking a $n^2$-fold direct sum of the identity
$A\otimes_F F\cong A$. Likewise $M_n(A)\cong A^{n^2}$ as $A$-modules.
Putting together the implied $A$-module isomorphisms
$$A\otimes_F M_n(F)\cong A\otimes_F F^{n^2}
\cong A^{n^2}\cong M_n(A)$$
gives the map you are considering, so it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Isomorphism as $A$-modules isn't the same as isomorphism as $A$-algebras

Comment: @egreg If an $A$-algebra homomorphism is an $A$-module isomorphism, then its an $A$-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: But why do you get an $A$-algebra homomorphism?

Comment: @egreg ZekeJay wrote one down.